# Vagrant port forwarding not working. Cups not accesible from host

Tags: vagrant, cups

So I'm working with vagrant and I'm trying to use it as a printing server. I installed cups.

Internally everything works just fine. I can even make a quick `curl` to my localhost:631 (cups port inside my vagrant) and there's everything.

The thing is I cant access it in any way I try from the host machine.

Obviously I forwarded the port and I've tried with several ports. I've also tried with Debian squeeze and Ubuntu 12.04. Here is my current `Vagrantfile`

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|                                              
  config.vm.box = "guruDebian"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 631, host: 6363   ## HERE IS CUPS           
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you will find is that the default cups config file is locked down to only work from localhost for security reasons.

Inside your Vagrant VM open the `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` file and change the following line:

```
Listen localhost:631
```

to

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:631
```

That should allow you to connect from any host.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem!.. When I did this it caused a `Bad Request` error which I solved by adding `ServerAlias *` to /etc/cups/cupsd.conf and everything worked like a charm. 
Thanks again.

Comment: @AAlvz `ServerAlias *` really helps me a lot! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing port 8080 of guest to your host? if no, and the services inside guest are running. then its a firewall issue in guest.

Try to turn firewall temporarily

> service iptables off

then try to access it again from host.