# Cannot reach Jekyll server on Vagrant from outside

Tags: vagrant, jekyll

I've built a Vagrant VM with hashicorp/precise32 box and installed Jekyll on it. I've set port 4000 forwarding on Vagrantfile:

`config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 4000, guest: 4000`

When I try `jekyll server` it seems everything works fine, but I cannot reach the server from outside.

```
Configuration file: /vagrant/test-site/_config.yml
Source: /vagrant/test-site
Destination: /vagrant/test-site/_site
Generating...
                done.
Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/vagrant/test-site'
Configuration file: /vagrant/test-site/_config.yml
Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

When I try to reach the server via curl, the output is:

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was aborted
```

I've tried with other servers on same port and I can reach them, so it not seems a forwarding problem.

Any idea?

Edited:

`curl localhost:4000` works correctly inside VM. For some reason, the port forwarding is not working properly for Jekyll.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The error was on `Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/`. It seems that localhost is the default host for Jekyll, so I need to run `jekyll serve --host 0.0.0.0` for the server to be available from outside.

I find the answer here: [Vagrant port forwarding not working. Cups not accesible from host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19571708/vagrant-port-forwarding-not-working-cups-not-accesible-from-host?rq=1)