# Debugging Tomcat Running in Vagrant using Port Forwarding

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat, vagrant

I'm trying to attach my Eclipse debugger running on my Windows host to a Tomcat 8 server running in my Vagrant box running CentOS 7.

The issue is something to do with the networking setup of Vagrant I believe.

Here is the full error from the Eclipse logs:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:189)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.SocketTransportService.readHandshake(SocketTransportService.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.SocketTransportService.access$7(SocketTransportService.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.SocketTransportService$3.run(SocketTransportService.java:183)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

The output from `vagrant up` seems correct (port 8000 is the debugging port):

```
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 8000 => 8000 (adapter 1)
    default: 8443 => 8443 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
```

I can access my application (using https://localhost:8443/app) via a browser from my host without issue; connecting the debugger is the issue. The debugger is configured for a Remote Java Application with connection properties:

```
Host: localhost
Port: 8000
```

Starting Tomcat of course displays the correct:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
```

Based on the following questions, the answer maybe have something to do with configuring Tomcat to run on `0.0.0.0` instead of the default:

[Cannot reach Jekyll server on Vagrant from outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617217/cannot-reach-jekyll-server-on-vagrant-from-outside)
[Vagrant port forwarding not working. Cups not accesible from host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19571708/vagrant-port-forwarding-not-working-cups-not-accesible-from-host?rq=1)
[Empty reply from server - can't connect to vagrant vm w/port forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840098/empty-reply-from-server-cant-connect-to-vagrant-vm-w-port-forwarding?rq=1)
[Connection Reset when port forwarding with Vagrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157353/connection-reset-when-port-forwarding-with-vagrant)

So I tried configuring the Connectors in Tomcat's server.xml with the line `address="0.0.0.0"` but the result was the same.

Any other ideas about getting this to work? Also, assuming the answer is something to do with changing the address to `0.0.0.0`, why would I need to do that to get the debugger to work if accessing the app via browser is already fine on `localhost:8443`?

P.S. It is not a firewall issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was on the right track above changing the address to `0.0.0.0`, but I was changing that on the `Connector` in server.xml, which has nothing to do with the debugger. The resolution is to change the `JPDA_ADDRESS` resulting in my `bin/setenv.sh` getting:

```
JPDA_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:8000"
```

This is due to a [change in Tomcat 8](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html):

> When starting Tomcat with the jpda option to enable remote debugging,
>   Tomcat 8 listens on localhost:8000 by default. Earlier versions
>   listened on *:8000. If required, this default can be overridden by
>   setting the JPDA_ADDRESS environment variable in, for example,
>   setenv.[bat|sh].